# Easiest way make API call using Javascript + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am trying to make an API call to Openweathermap using their API+key. I am unable to parse the data to a CSS ID using $.getJSON in Javascript.

This is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lz3vf0/

Code:

```
var weatherData = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
q=Endicott,us&appid=API+KEY";

$.getJSON(weatherData, function(data){
var town = data.name;

document.getElementById('town').innerHTML = town;
});
```

And it outputs to a simple div tag

Obviously the end result will be far more involved and I will be parsing much more data, but in the jsfiddle, it should simply output my city name but it's not.

Comment: The JSFiddle link is HTTPS, and your code attempts to call a HTTP endpoint. Using OpenWeatherMap via HTTPS or JSFiddle via HTTP will work (or both).

Comment: My friend, that worked. Thank you. How did you know that was the problem?

Comment: If you open the console in the JSFiddle tab, you can see the following error: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mixed content error on the jsfiddle page, because it's a https website and you're trying to call a http url in your API call. You can't call an external API using http if you're over https, the request is blocked.

I tried your request with https and it works just as expected.

Comment: Thank you, like the other comment said, this was the problem. I was tearing my hair out.